# How can I convert stereo audio to binaural?

Tags: sound, mplayer

I have looked around and I came across ([b2sb](http://b2sb.sourceforge.net)) and well its not clear how to install it. It also mentions there that it is used in MPlayer but I can't see how.

So how do I go about installing it?

As a further extension, I'd like to have virtual 5.1 on my headphones. I know Dolby Headphone does this and there's a Foobar2000 plugin in Windows but that applies to audio only. There is the HRTF implementation of MPlayer but there's lots of crackles and pops when its enabled.

Answer (score 1):

This is a plugin for ALSA.

Go to Sourceforge download page and download the [LADSPA plug-in package](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=151236).

```
cd folder_where_you_downloaded_the_package
tar xf ladspa-bs2b-VERSION.tar.X # the VERSION and X depend on the downloaded version and package type
cd ladspa-bs2b-VERSION
./configure --prefix=/usr # Prefix may be different depending on your distribution but usually /usr is fine
make
su -c "make install"
```

Plus there is a FOOBAR 2000 plugin also

**Source:** [Stereo to binaural with ALSA using bs2b LADSPA plug-in](http://www.rpgameplace.de/blog/index.php?/archives/21-Stereo-to-binaural-with-ALSA-using-bs2b-LADSPA-plug-in.html)

Comment: Thanks for that. I saw that article before posting. So, how I understand it creates a new "device" in the output devices area so we can choose that and then all audio gets routed through the bs2b LADSPA plug-in? Is there no GUI way as such to define a configuration that does the same?

Comment: there is Gnome ALSA mixer in the software center

Comment: I don't see any options to add "devices" in Gnome ALSA Mixer. Think I will try the Jack approach..